# Pylint error: Module Pythoncom has no member

Tags: python, pylint

I am new to python and is using visual studio code and i have also installed pywin32. However when i run the program it says that pythoncom module does not have both CoInitialize and CoUninitialize member.

I would like to know how can i make the pythoncom recognize those two members ?

```
import os

if os.name == 'nt':
   import pythoncom
class PlatformHelper: 

   def __init__(self):
       if os.name == 'nt':
           pythoncom.CoInitialize()

   def __del__(self):                
       if os.name == 'nt':
           pythoncom.CoUninitialize() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("roypy_platform_utils is a utility module, it doesn't expect to be run directly")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running pylint with `--extension-pkg-whitelist=pythoncom`? If pythoncom is a C Python module, then pylint will have a hard time understanding its structure, given that the code is most likely in C. In that case, when you specify that flag, you notify pylint to import the module in order to build an AST from the live object, which usually helps with these kind of errors.